# Hardware device to evaluate several sensors

Tags: electrical-engineering

Two tanks with three continuos, redundant level sensors each need to be supervised so that when a certain total volume is reached, a specific actor is triggered. This could be done via the installed PLC system, however it is likely that a regulatory body will demand a hardware solution. However SIL compliance is not demanded. The important thing is that it's hard to alter the function or change parameters.

So I need a device that can do the following:

- Take average from three analog signals for tank 1, add offset
- same for tank 2
- add both values and give a digital signal to trigger if total exceeds a certain value
- don't add value for tank 1 or 2 to the total, if a maintenance switch assigned to this tank is on

Can this be done in a logic module? If so what specifications (not the specific model) do I need? If not, what's the device called and how to specify?

Comment: Can you please tell us more about the  redundant level sensors? Is it possible to share a picture or sketch of the tank? What are electrical characteristics of the three analog signals?

Comment: no picture, just three sensors measuring essentially the same level

Comment: How about electrical characteristics of the three analog signals from the sensors?

Comment: You can use op amps to add the signals, or you could use a parallel output ADC (if those still exist) followed by a whole bunch of logic chips. Neither is a very elegant solution.

Comment: 4-20 mA each. I need a prepackaged solution.

Comment: @mart, is there data sheet for the  level sensors

Comment: 4-20 mA signals are actually easy to add in analog, but that is several decades out of date. For both flexibility, robustness, and fault detection too, this is clearly a task for PLC logic. To get it to be "quasi tamper proof", you may need to go a step beyond ladder logic (create a function block???), which will make it illegible to 95% of the PLC world, but that's life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the major industrial PLC manufacturers make micro PLCs.

[image]

*Figure 1. Siemens LOGO! base module with built-in HMI and keypad. A larger panel-mounted remote display is available.*

The base unit has up to four analog inputs which are 0 - 10 V. You may require 3 × 2-channel 4 - 20 mA analog input modules.

[image]

*Figure 2. Most of the program requirements done for Siemens LOGO! using Logosoft Comfort and running in the simulator. Download over Ethernet. Double-click for full size view.*

- The analog inputs go through an analog amplifier for scaling. The AM (analog markers) are required to terminate the analog signal as far as I can remember.
- AVERAGE 1 takes sums the three analog signals and divides by 3.
- The SUM block sums TANK 1 and TANK 2.
- The COMPARE block compares against the setpoint. I've added some hysteresis.

The only thing left for you is to add in some MUX (multiplexor) blocks to output a zero if the maintenance switch is on.

---

I strongly recommend that you avoid hobby boards for industrial controls. PLCs are hardened for industrial environments, have proper isolation between inputs / outputs and control and are very reliable and have a large userbase.

If there is **any danger to personnel or property** then you need a fail-safe system or fail-safe backup system in conjunction with the PLC. Once you install this you will be liable.

Comment: How would you tamper proof a micro plc?

Comment: Use password protection. The Siemens LOGO! series have it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Analog input modules from [National Instruments](https://www.ni.com/en-us/shop/hardware/products/c-series-voltage-and-current-input-module.html) similar to the one below.

[image]

This is prepackaged solution Labview software controlled solution.

Another good place to look at is hobby electronic market.

Some suggestion are

- [**Beaglebone Black**](https://beagleboard.org/black)

[image]

- [**Arduino**](https://www.arduino.cc/)

[image]

- [**Raspberry Pi**](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/)

[image]

Based on the information provided either of the above will be able assist in achieving your end goal. All of the above have the ability to accept analog inputs.